# Uploading Images before website appear to users

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want images in my website uploaded before website appear to users , my website looks bad before background-image uploaded , how can I do that ? thanx

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a loader that wait body load (with javascript) and then shows the website...
To create the loader, please read [this article](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/).